# What can an LED electroluminescence emission spectrum be used for?

Tags: experimental-physics, semiconductor-physics

We did a lab session where we obtained such a spectrum. Why would this be of interest?

It's possible this wasn't explained because we have very little background knowledge of how LEDs work, so the experiment was done purely to familiarise us with certain equipment, but I'm curious. I have since read up on the theory but still can't really see why it's a useful measurement.

Comment: @CountTo10 Thank you, your answer was very helpful! :) It enabled me to find specific information that can be extracted, for example by measuring at different temperatures changes in bandgap can be observed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We did a lab session where we obtained such a spectrum. Why would this be of interest?

The short answer:
To help develop improved  semiconducting devices and to gain increased knowledge concerning related condensed matter issues.

The longer version:

You obtained a particular spectrum, and the equation underlying it is based
on the spontaneous emission rate, which in turn  is determined by the photon energy, utilising the formula:

$$ K_{sp}(\omega) = \frac  {1}{\tau_r}g_j(\omega) f_e(\hbar \omega) $$

Where  the emission condition is given by 
$g_j (E)$is the joint density of states and $f_e(E)$ is the joint occupation probability for the valence and conduction bands.

In the above situation, we are seeking an estimation of the number of states available to holes and electrons. When these recombine, they produce photons of a given frequency. The parabolic approximation is put to use to  determine the joint density of states at the band edge.

To find out more regarding the relevence of the density of states (DOS), please see [Density of States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states) and similarly for the usefulness of the parabolic approximation.

> The density of states plays an important role in the kinetic theory of solids. The product of the density of states and the probability distribution function is the number of occupied states per unit volume at a given energy for a system in thermal equilibrium. This value is widely used to investigate various physical properties of matter.

The link I have listed above, invoving probability  distribution functions, also provides examples of the role such functions can play in creating distinct  physical properties